# Angular 6 - Rendering problems if BrowserAnimationsModule imported (Openlayers)

Tags: angular, openlayers, angular6, lifecycle, angular-animations

I basically have a App which renders a small map. On this page is also a "toggle" button which hides the small map with a *ngIf in the parent component and displays the map in large instead. 
If I now import BrowserAnimationsModule in app.module.ts the large map is not rendered if I click on the toggle button (only if i set a timeout of 1ms before the map is created in ngOnInit of map-base.component.ts).

Sorry..it's a bit hard to explain, here's the code:

**App.module.ts**

```
...
@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    AppComponent,
    MapSmallComponent,
    MapLargeComponent,
    MapBaseComponent
  ],
  imports: [
    BrowserModule,
    FormsModule,
    BrowserAnimationsModule, // comment this line, to make the app work
  ],
  providers: [],
  bootstrap: [AppComponent]
})
export class AppModule { }
```

**app.component.ts**

```
@Component({
  selector: 'app-root',
  template: `
  <app-map-small *ngIf="small"></app-map-small>
  <app-map-large *ngIf="!small"></app-map-large>
  <button (click)="small = !small">Toggle</button>`,
  styleUrls: ['./app.component.scss']
})
export class AppComponent {
  small = true;
}
```

**map-base.component.ts**

```
@Component({
  selector: 'app-map-base',
  template: `<div id="map" class="map"></div>`,
  styleUrls: ['./map-base.component.scss']
})
export class MapBaseComponent implements OnInit {
  map: OlMap;
  constructor() { }

  ngOnInit() {
    this.map = new OlMap({
      target: 'map',
      layers: [new OlTileLayer({ source: new OlOSM() })],
      view: new OlView({ zoom: 13, center: fromLonLat([13.376935, 52.516181]) }),
      controls: []
    });
  }
}
```

**map-small.component.ts**

```
@Component({
  selector: 'app-map-small',
  template: `
    <p>other stuff</p>
    <div style="max-width:500px">
      <app-map-base></app-map-base>
    </div>
    <p>other stuff2</p>
  `,
  styleUrls: ['./map-small.component.scss']
})
export class MapSmallComponent implements OnInit {

  constructor() { }

  ngOnInit() {
  }
}
```

**map-large.component.ts**

```
@Component({
  selector: 'app-map-large',
  template: `
  <p>Some other stuff</p>
  <app-map-base></app-map-base>`,
  styleUrls: ['./map-large.component.scss']
})
export class MapLargeComponent implements OnInit {

  constructor() { }

  ngOnInit() {
  }
}
```

**dependencies**

```
"dependencies": {
    "@angular/animations": "^6.0.9",
    "@angular/cdk": "^6.4.0",
    "@angular/common": "^6.0.2",
    "@angular/compiler": "^6.0.2",
    "@angular/core": "^6.0.2",
    "@angular/forms": "^6.0.2",
    "@angular/http": "^6.0.2",
    "@angular/material": "^6.4.0",
    "@angular/platform-browser": "^6.0.2",
    "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "^6.0.2",
    "@angular/router": "^6.0.2",
    "core-js": "^2.5.4",
    "ol": "^5.1.3",
    "rxjs": "^6.0.0",
    "zone.js": "^0.8.26"
  },
```

So why works everything fine, if I don't import BrowserAnimationsModule and it breaks if I import it? I want to use Angular Material, that's I would need it...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is a solution,

Component template

```html
<div #mapElementRef class="map"></div>
```

Component class implements `OnInit` and has the next property

```js
@ViewChild('mapElementRef', { static: true }) mapElementRef: ElementRef;
```

finally initialize the map on `ngOnInit` method, you can use

```js
this.map.setTarget(this.mapElementRef.nativeElement);
```

Hope it helps.

Answer (score 0):

You have to use [`ngAfterViewInit`](https://angular.io/api/core/AfterViewInit), then you can be 'sure' the element inside your components template is present in the DOM.

```
ngAfterViewInit() {
  this.map = new OlMap({
    target: 'map',
    layers: [new OlTileLayer({ source: new OlOSM() })],
    view: new OlView({ zoom: 13, center: fromLonLat([13.376935, 52.516181]) }),
    controls: []
  });
}
```

Answer (score 0):

*Attention dirty fix*
I did try the version of @cabesuon but it still wasn't working.

Like @cabueson said, do

```html
<div #mapElementRef class="map"></div>
```

And then in your `component.ts`, but

- infantilize it under the `ngAfterViewInit()` *as @PoulKrujit said*
- add the `setTimeout(() => {})` *this is the dirty fix*

Here the result

```js
export class MapBaseComponent implements AfterViewInit {
  @ViewChild('mapElementRef', { static: true }) mapElementRef: ElementRef

  map: OlMap

  constructor() {}

  ngAfterViewInit() {
    setTimeout(() => {
      this.map = new Map({
        layers: [new OlTileLayer({ source: new OlOSM() })],
        view: new OlView({ zoom: 13, center: fromLonLat([13.376935, 52.516181]) }),
        controls: [],
      })

      this.map.setTarget(this.mapElementRef.nativeElement)
    }, 0)
  }
}
```

I'm not 100% sure why, but that's my guess.
`ion-content` does not refresh himself once instantiate. But, putting the code under the timeout force ion-content to be refreshed. It's also the reason why you don't have to put any millisecond.

Other whay to force the ionic app to refresh does exists, `tick` for example, but timeout is good enough for what we're doing here.

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar issue, and solved it differently. Let me share with you what I learned.

I have an Angular (13) app, with two components that can be displayed exclusively thanks to a router-outlet... So my App looks like that :

```
// App.component.html
<router-outlet>

// App.route.module.ts
const routes: Routes = [
  { path: 'map-component', component: MapComponent },
  { path: 'settings', component: SettingsComponent },
];
```

The map-component is my default route. So when I start my application everything is fine.

But when I enable the "settings" route, my MapComponent is destroyed, then when I go back to "map-component", during some frames I can see that both components are presents in the DOM (as shown in screen shot bellow) :

[image]

So what I did in my map component to solve this issue is the following code :

```
// Map.component.ts

export class MapComponent implements AfterViewInit, DoCheck {
private previousHeight = 0;
@ViewChild('map') map!: ElementRef;


ngAfterViewInit(): void {
    this.previousHeight = this.map.nativeElement.offsetHeight;
    this.mapService.map.setTarget(this.map.nativeElement);
  }

  ngDoCheck(): void {
     if (this.map) {
      if(this.previousHeight !== this.map.nativeElement.offsetHeight) {
        this.previousHeight = this.map.nativeElement.offsetHeight;
        this.mapService.map.updateSize();
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Because Angular call the DoCheck method during animation, I update the map size all along the animation.

I am not fully satisfied of that method. What I really would like is to disable the router animation (and keep all other animation). Buf even after looking in the angular documentation, I can't find any thing about this "default animation"...