# OL map with low quality using Ionic

Tags: angular, ionic-framework, mobile, openlayers

I'm trying to load the OL map with Ionic. When I load it with 'ionic serve' the map load fine in the browser. The problem is when I load the map in mobile, the map quality gets really low. This happened to me once in a web app when the map container changed the size and the map don't load again. In the web app I fixed it by applying a function that realoaded the map after the container change it's size, something like this:

```
$('#containerMap').on('change', function () {
  setTimeout(function(){ map.updateSize(); }, 500);
});
```

I tried to apply the same function in the home.ts page, but no success.
After some research I see some people saying that the right way to load the map is with Ionic Components, but I can't replicate from the examples.

**Ionic v4 & OpenLayers v5.3**

The Ionic Components related answers:

- [Angular 6 - Rendering problems if BrowserAnimationsModule imported (Openlayers)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51838726/angular-6-rendering-problems-if-browseranimationsmodule-imported-openlayers/54281422#54281422)
- [Ionic-Framework (4) - Openlayers map not working/visible](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54105934/ionic-framework-4-openlayers-map-not-working-visible/54281445#54281445)

Other example that I followed:

- https://stackblitz.com/edit/ionic-nz2cgw?file=pages%2Fhome%2Fhome.ts

What I'm trying to do (home-page.ts):

```
import { Component, Renderer, ViewChild } from '@angular/core';
import { NavController, Platform } from '@ionic/angular';
import { Map } from 'ol';
import { OSM, Vector as VectorSource } from 'ol/source.js';
import Point from 'ol/geom/Point.js';
import Feature from 'ol/Feature';
import { transform } from 'ol/proj.js';
import { Icon, Style } from 'ol/style.js';
import { Vector as VectorLayer } from 'ol/layer.js';
import View from 'ol/View.js';
import TileLayer from 'ol/layer/Tile.js';


@Component({
  selector: 'app-home',
  templateUrl: 'home.page.html',
  styleUrls: ['home.page.scss'],
})

export class HomePage {
    @ViewChild('map') map;
    constructor(platform: Platform, public renderer: Renderer) {
        platform.ready().then(() => {
          console.log("Platform is ready");
          setTimeout(() => {
             this.loadMap();
           }, 1000);
        })  
    }

    // I tried to load the map with this function first, but it was not loaded.
    //ionViewDidLoad() {
    //  this.loadMap();
    //}

    loadMap() {
      console.log('Hello');

      var map = new Map({
        layers: [
            new TileLayer({ 
                source: new OSM()
            })],
        target: document.getElementById('map'),
        view: new View({
          center: [0, 0],
          zoom: 3
        })
      });
      map.updateSize(); //Tried to apply the same function used in web
    }
}
```

Differences in app and web:
[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems to be a device problem. If I try to open an OL online example like [this](https://openlayers.org/en/latest/examples/mobile-full-screen.html) in the mobile, emulator or physical device, the same problem occurs.