# How can I use Openlayers5 with ionic-angular

Tags: typescript, ionic4, angular8, openlayers-5

The problem is that I am using Typescript 3.4.3 and the OpenLayer API is been documented only for Javascript. Somewhere I found that I need to install @types/ol": "^5.3.3" in order to use Openlayer with Typescript.

I have the following code but I do not get any error but also the map is not visible. I can not understand where the problem is.

I Did try some solutions that other users found useful like:

a) [Ionic-Framework (4) - Openlayers map not working/visible](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54105934/ionic-framework-4-openlayers-map-not-working-visible)
(using a setTimeout)

b) https://stackoverflow.com/a/54281422/11873024

None of them works

map.page.ts

```
import Tile from 'ol/layer/Tile';
import Map from 'ol/Map';
import View from 'ol/View';
import OSM from 'ol/source/OSM';


@Component({
  selector: 'app-home',
  templateUrl: 'home.page.html',
  styleUrls: ['home.page.scss'],
})
export class HomePage implements OnInit {

  private map: Map;
  // @ts-ignore
  // b) @ViewChild('mapElementRef') mapElementRef: ElementRef;
  constructor() {}

  initializeMap() {
    this.map = new Map({
      target: 'map',
      layers: [
        new Tile({
          source: new OSM()
        }),
      ],
      view: new View({
        center: [0, 0],
        zoom: 3
      }),
    });
  }

  ngOnInit() {
    this.initializeMap();
    // b) this.map.setTarget(this.mapElementRef.nativeElement);


  }

}
```

map.page.html

```
<ion-content>
  <div class="ion-padding">
    <h3>Map Here!</h3>
  </div>
  <div id="map" class="map">
  </div>

</ion-content>
```

I expected an error or a map, but i got nothing so I don't know what to search.

Comment: I think you are missing `#mapElementRef` on the template, it should be `<div #mapElementRef id="map" class="map"></div>`, and then the target of the map should be `this.mapElementRef.nativeElement`

Comment: @cabesuon I forgot to remove the last row of code. I was in the middle of trying too many things in order to succeed it (I will edit my code). I tried the suggestion you said but still nothing. With or without the nativeElement its the same

Comment: If you are going to use target with a dom id you have to add a timeout, in your code should be something like `ngOnInit() {
    setTimeout(_ => this.initializeMap(), 2000);
  }`

Comment: Btw, I am asumming you are seeing the zoom buttons but the OSM is not showing, that you specified a size to the map container div in home.page.scss, and you are importing ol.css.

Comment: Your assumption was correct. I was viewing the buttons and nothing else. Now with the timeout I can see the map ( and the buttons if I remove the scss I declared).
It's weird because i Did try with setTimeout for 1000ms before and it didn't work.

Comment: Some personal advice: Take a look at https://leafletjs.com/. A few weeks ago I needed a simple map to visualize the location of some objects on a map and chose OpenLayers... After much work I finally got it working, only to realize that I just doubled my bundle size: This thing is HUGE.

Comment: @FabianN. Yes I need to do the same simple thing. I have leafletjs.com in mind too. I finally got working the OpenLayers but yes indeed is heavy. Thanks both of you for the advises.