# I can't display the openlayer map properly until after a window resize

Tags: angular, typescript, ionic-framework, openlayers

I set up the map like this:

```
this.map = new Map({
  target: 'map',
  layers: [new TileLayer({source: new OSM()})
  ],
  view: new View({
    center: [0, 0],
    zoom: 16,
  })
});
```

On opening the page I get this:

[before resizing](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WdcmF.png)

So I open the console to make the page smaller and the map is loaded:

[after resizing](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Qy3XC.png)

Do you have any idea how to fix it?

Comment: It seems like a timing issue, can you add the code of the component where the map is bound

Comment: actually I set the map in the on-init hook

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I solved the problem for me. It was actually a timing issue. The solution is the following: I inserted an ng-if on the html element. and set the target of the map after a one-second time-out.

html:

```
<ion-item *ngIf="loaded">
  <div id="map" [ngClass]="{'map': loaded}"></div>
</ion-item>
```

.ts:

```
this.map = new Map({
  view: new View({
    center: [0, 0],
    zoom: 16,
    minZoom: 2,
    maxZoom: 19
  }),
  layers: [
    new TileLayer({
      source: new OSM()
    }),
  ]
});
this.loaded = true;
setTimeout(() => {
  this.map.setTarget(document.getElementById('map'));
}, 1000);
```

Answer (score 1):

I did the following:

```
import { AfterViewInit, Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import Map from 'ol/Map';
import View from 'ol/View';
import TileLayer from 'ol/layer/Tile';
import OSM from 'ol/source/OSM';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-root',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./app.component.scss'],
})
export class AppComponent implements OnInit, AfterViewInit {
  map!: Map;

  ngOnInit(): void {
    let view = new View({
      center: [0, 0],
      zoom: 1,
    });

    let layers = [
      new TileLayer({
        source: new OSM(),
      }),
    ];

    this.map = new Map({
      view: view,
      layers: layers,
      target: 'ol-map',
    });

    this.map.updateSize();
  }

  ngAfterViewInit(): void {
    this.map.updateSize();
  }
}
```

I think this is a clean way of solving this problem since in `ngOnInit` we define the map and we just update it's size once the view is initialized. Simple and effective.

Answer (score 0):

A bit more than a year ago I answer a similar question. Take a look at the question [Angular 6 - Rendering problems if BrowserAnimationsModule imported (Openlayers)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51838726/angular-6-rendering-problems-if-browseranimationsmodule-imported-openlayers/54281422#54281422)
.

There you will find a couple of solutions, one uses `OnInit` method of the component plus `ViewChild` to get the reference element to bind the map. The other proposal uses `AfterViewInit`.

Answer (score 0):

I am updating window then it works

```
setTimeout(() => {
        oMap.updateSize();
    }, 0);
```

Comment: well adding updateSize() in setTimeOut() works