# Openlayers map not draggable

Tags: angular, typescript, components, maps, openlayers

I want to show map in simple angular web site. Code of component.ts is

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import 'ol/ol.css';
import Map from 'ol/Map';
import View from 'ol/View';
import TileLayer from 'ol/layer/Tile';
import {OSM, TileDebug} from 'ol/source';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-map',
  templateUrl: './map.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./map.component.css']
})
export class MapComponent implements OnInit {

  constructor() { }

  ngOnInit(): void {
    var map = new Map({
      layers: [
        new TileLayer({
          source: new OSM()
        }),
        new TileLayer({
          source: new TileDebug()
        })
      ],
      target: 'mapdiv',
      view: new View({
        center: [0, 0],
        zoom: 1
      })
    });
  }
}
```

and code for  component.html is

```
<div id = 'mapdiv'></div>
```

Map is showing on the in browser (Chrome )but its not movable (draggable).

Comment: just to clarify, you are seeing the map, both OSM and debug, but you can not pan?

Comment: Yes. Map is visible, but I cannot pan and zoom in.

Comment: See https://github.com/openlayers/openlayers/issues/10732

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After I added following in my component.html file, it worked fine.

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://openlayers.org/en/v6.2.1/css/ol.css" type="text/css">
```

Thnaks guys for your support!!!

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at this answer I made like an year ago [I can't display the openlayer map properly until after a window resize](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60775376/i-cant-display-the-openlayer-map-properly-until-after-a-window-resize/60780381#60780381).

Although the problem is a bit different, I think that it might be related. In the way you are creating the component you have a timing issue, that can cause that the map is not show or it might cause something like your case.

In that question, you also have another solution that could also fit the problem.