# OpenLayers: How to get the WMS Time animated map to load without resizing in an R Shiny app?

Tags: javascript, animation, shiny, resize, openlayers

In this R Shiny app

https://github.com/DanielEWeeks/NWS_WeatherShinyApp

I have added the WMS Time animated weather radar map from this OpenLayers example

https://openlayers.org/en/latest/examples/wms-time.html

to the `Radar` tab, but the animated map does not load until after the tab window is resized.

Following these suggestions

[I can't display the openlayer map properly until after a window resize](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60775376/i-cant-display-the-openlayer-map-properly-until-after-a-window-resize)

I tried inserting various combinations of

`map.updateSize();`

commands into a `script` block in the `radar.html` file, but that did not work.

Would appreciate any guidance you might be able to provide re how to make the OpenLayers `Radar` tab load properly when it is first loaded, without requiring a resize event.

This uses this `main.js` from https://openlayers.org/en/latest/examples/wms-time.html

```
import Map from 'ol/Map.js';
import Stamen from 'ol/source/Stamen.js';
import TileLayer from 'ol/layer/Tile.js';
import TileWMS from 'ol/source/TileWMS.js';
import View from 'ol/View.js';
import {getCenter} from 'ol/extent.js';
import {transformExtent} from 'ol/proj.js';

function threeHoursAgo() {
  return new Date(Math.round(Date.now() / 3600000) * 3600000 - 3600000 * 3);
}

const extent = transformExtent([-126, 24, -66, 50], 'EPSG:4326', 'EPSG:3857');
let startDate = threeHoursAgo();
const frameRate = 0.5; // frames per second
let animationId = null;

const layers = [
  new TileLayer({
    source: new Stamen({
      layer: 'terrain',
    }),
  }),
  new TileLayer({
    extent: extent,
    source: new TileWMS({
      attributions: ['Iowa State University'],
      url: 'https://mesonet.agron.iastate.edu/cgi-bin/wms/nexrad/n0r-t.cgi',
      params: {'LAYERS': 'nexrad-n0r-wmst'},
    }),
  }),
];
const map = new Map({
  layers: layers,
  target: 'map',
  view: new View({
    center: getCenter(extent),
    zoom: 5,
  }),
});

function updateInfo() {
  const el = document.getElementById('info');
  el.innerHTML = startDate.toISOString();
}

function setTime() {
  startDate.setMinutes(startDate.getMinutes() + 15);
  if (startDate > Date.now()) {
    startDate = threeHoursAgo();
  }
  layers[1].getSource().updateParams({'TIME': startDate.toISOString()});
  updateInfo();
}
setTime();

const stop = function () {
  if (animationId !== null) {
    window.clearInterval(animationId);
    animationId = null;
  }
};

const play = function () {
  stop();
  animationId = window.setInterval(setTime, 1000 / frameRate);
};

const startButton = document.getElementById('play');
startButton.addEventListener('click', play, false);

const stopButton = document.getElementById('pause');
stopButton.addEventListener('click', stop, false);

updateInfo();
```

Possible solutions tried:

```
  tabPanel("Radar",
           tags$script("setTimeout(() => {
  map.updateSize();
}, 10);"),
           includeHTML("radar.html"))
  )
```

This gave an error about map having a zero height or width.

--

Put this in end of the 'head' section or at the end of the 'body' section of 'radar.html':

```
  <script>
    setTimeout(() => {
       map.updateSize();
    }, 10);
  </script>
```

This gave this error

```
TypeError: map.updateSize is not a function
```

--

**Solution**

To get the animated weather map to load within an R Shiny tabPanel without requiring a manual window resize, this adjusted code works. Note that it uses two approaches suggested/discussed in other posts:

1. Most of the code is lies within a `$(document).ready(function()` call.
2. The code auto-resizes the map via a call to `map.updateSize()` when the tab panel is selected:

```
      $("a[data-toggle=\'tab\']").on("shown.bs.tab", function() {
        map.updateSize();
      }
```

Here's more of the code in context (complete code available at https://github.com/DanielEWeeks/NWS_WeatherShinyApp):

```
  tags$script(HTML('
    var startDate = new Date(Math.round(Date.now() / 3600000) * 3600000 - 3600000 * 3);
    var frameRate = 2; // frames per second
    var animationId = null;
    var tileLayer;
    var timeInfo;
    var currentAnimationFrame = null;
    var map;

    function updateInfo() {
      timeInfo.innerHTML = "Current Time: " + startDate.toISOString();
    }

    function setTime() {
      startDate.setMinutes(startDate.getMinutes() + 15);
      if (startDate > Date.now()) {
        startDate = new Date(Math.round(Date.now() / 3600000) * 3600000 - 3600000 * 3);
      }
      var timeParam = startDate.toISOString();
      tileLayer.getSource().updateParams({ TIME: timeParam });
      updateInfo();
    }

    function stop() {
      if (currentAnimationFrame !== null) {
        clearInterval(currentAnimationFrame);
        currentAnimationFrame = null;
      }
    }

    function play() {
      stop();
      currentAnimationFrame = setInterval(setTime, 1000 / frameRate);
    }

    $(document).ready(function() {
      tileLayer = new ol.layer.Tile({
        extent: ol.proj.transformExtent([-126, 24, -66, 50], "EPSG:4326", "EPSG:3857"),
        source: new ol.source.TileWMS({
          attributions: ["Iowa State University"],
          url: "https://mesonet.agron.iastate.edu/cgi-bin/wms/nexrad/n0r-t.cgi",
          params: { LAYERS: "nexrad-n0r-wmst" }
        })
      });

      map = new ol.Map({
        target: "map",
        layers: [
          new ol.layer.Tile({
            source: new ol.source.OSM()
          }),
          tileLayer
        ],
        view: new ol.View({
          center: ol.proj.fromLonLat([-98.5, 39.5]),
          zoom: 5
        })
      });

      timeInfo = document.getElementById("time-info");

      $("#play-button").on("click", function() {
        play();
      });

      $("#pause-button").on("click", function() {
        stop();
      });

      updateInfo();
      play();

      // Resize the map when the tab is selected
      $("a[data-toggle=\'tab\']").on("shown.bs.tab", function() {
        map.updateSize();
      });
    });
  ')
```